# Intent filter and wwwXX (numbers after www)

Tags: android

How would one "cleanly" implement intent filters for a host like wwwXX.site.com? I would rather not account for each possible combo ever, as that'd be too much of a pain.

Can wildcards somehow be used there to achieve what I want cleanly?

Comment: Is it always the same site? site.com?

Comment: The site is always the same, it's the www-part that is different.